# printf() with %c format code not printing what I expect

Tags: c, printing

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( ) {
    int n;
    n = 0;
    printf ("%c\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

so that's my code, but when i print it, it just prints a blank space. Shouldn't it print 0?

Comment: It is a good practice to try to understand why it printed a "blank space"..

Comment: `%c` prints a character.  Character 0 displays as blank.  Set the variable `n` to the value `65` and it will print a capital `A` character.

Answer (score 1):

Change %c by %d:

```
printf ("%d\n", n);
```

Comment: that does work, but the question says only to change n not the printf statement

EDIT: oh, I did n='0'
surprising that even works

Answer (score 0):

n is integer type so try to print it as..

```
printf("%d\n",n);
```

and if u use %c then its printing first byte's related char in ASCII table .

Answer (score 0):

`Printf` Writes the C string pointed by format to the standard output (stdout). If format includes format specifiers (subsequences beginning with %), the additional arguments following format are formatted and inserted in the resulting string replacing their respective specifiers.

Here you are Using wrong format specifier to print your value. `%c` used for printing variables of type `char`(character) . Use `%d` for `int`(integer).

Try this [Link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: i already know how to code in c++,java, and php and tiny bits of assembly. I just didn't know how printf works.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display `0` without changing the `printf` statement, the way to do it is to do

```
n = '0';
```

or

```
n = 48;
```

Take a look at [Ascii Table](http://www.asciitable.com/), to see the ascii value of 0.